# How to set MVC web application as a SignalR self-host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have searched a lot about **SignalR** but all I could found that I can only make `console` application as a **self-host** and client from script and .net code can access that server. My question is how can we set a **MVC Web application** as a **self-host**?

Ref [link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host).

Comment: Hi, Please refre thi http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding only `app.MapSignalR()` to my Startup class I added `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)`as well and MVC based SignalR server is ready to server.